# function for calculating sets intersections for venns diagrams

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to write a function for creating a "venn-diagrams" but not plotting them - I need to create table that resembles venn diagram that count how many values are ***equal*** to beforehand selected number lets say 4 in this case

So with artificial data below:

```
   how_much = 100
   A <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5) 
   B <- sample(how_much, replace = TRUE, x = 1:5)    
   VennData <- data.frame(A, B)
```

I need to create a table that would look something like:

```
count    A      B
 24     TRUE   TRUE
 20     TRUE   FALSE
 13     FALSE  TRUE
 43     FALSE  FALSE
```

Comment: What's being counted for the last row with only `FALSE`?

Comment: sorry my bad alredy updated question last line says that in both columns there is 43 values that are not equal to beforehand selected number lets say 4 in this example